# django.utils.thread_support in django 1.5

Tags: python, django, thread-safety

I'm trying to implement a django custom middleware that gives me access to the `request` object wherever I am in my project, based in [the one suggested here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201008/global_django_requests.html). That article was written a long time ago, and [django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) does not have the library `thread_support` where it was back then. What alternative should I use to accomplish a thread safe local store to store the request object? This is the code in the custom middleware:

```
from django.utils.thread_support import currentThread
_requests = {}

def get_request():
    return _requests[currentThread()]

class GlobalRequestMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[currentThread()] = request
```

And, of course, it raises an exception:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware myProject.middleware.global: 
"No module named thread_support"
```

### EDIT:

I found out a working fix:

```
from threading import local

_active = local()

def get_request():
    return _active.request

class GlobalRequestMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        _active.request = request
        return None
```

Now I have a question: Does it leads to a memory leak? what happens with `_active`? is it cleaned when the request dies? Anyway, There's a valid answer already posted. I'm going to accept it but any other (better, if possible) solution would be very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
from django.utils.thread_support import currentThread
currentThread()
```

with

```
from threading import current_thread
current_thread()
```

Comment: Why? This may be what the OP wants, but it doesn't explain anything. Does this function do the same thing as the old Django function? Is this solution better than using a threadlocal? If so, how and why?

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers, there is now a python package that provides a much more robust version of this middleware: [django-crequest](https://pypi.org/project/django-crequest/)